# XSL cannot parse with Firefox

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

When I run xml file in Firefox I get: "Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed." And when I run it in Chrome I get blank page.
This is XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="g.xsl"?>
    <forma>
        <unos>
            <ime>Marija</ime>
            <prezime>Rahman</prezime>
            <ulica>Glasinacka 8</ulica>
            <postBroj>11000</postBroj>
            <grad>Beograd</grad>
            <drzava>Srbija</drzava>
            <mobilni>0621912773</mobilni>
            <email>marijarahman@gmail.com</email>
            <korisnickoIme>maja</korisnickoIme>
            <lozinka>maja123</lozinka>
        </unos>
    </forma>
```

And this is XSLT  file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl ="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Ime</th>
                            <th>Grad</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="forma/unos">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <xsl:value select="ime"/>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <xsl:value select="grad"/>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `xsl:value` in XSLT. The instruction is called `xsl:value-of`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl ="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ime</th>
                        <th>Grad</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="forma/unos">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ime"/>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="grad"/>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Ime</th>
            <th>Grad</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Marija</th>
            <th>Beograd</th>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

On a more general note, it is not really useful to *debug* transformations in browsers, because often, there is no way to find out what went wrong (as you have noticed). Use an IDE like Oxygen, or a simple command line processor like Saxon 9.5.

If you had run your stylesheet with command line Saxon, it would have told you immediately what's wrong. Here is the error message you would have seen in Oxygen:

```
E [Saxon6.5.5] Unknown XSLT element: value
```

which is a lot more helpful than

```
Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.
```

from Internet Explorer, or nothing from Chrome.

That said, once you've established that your stylesheet is correct, *running* the transformation in the browser might be a good idea, because then the transformation is done client-side.

Comment: Agreed that it's painful to *debug* transformations in browsers, because their error detection and messaging is so uniformly poor.  But it can nevertheless be very useful to *run* transformations in the browser -- doing so moves CPU costs from a server which may be constrained, to a client which often has CPU cycles to spare.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen You are right, I should have been more precise. I have edited my answer.